# Error in K-means algorithm

Tags: c, opencv, k-means

I use the following call to openCV function to perform K-means algorithm:

```
cvKMeans2(points, count, &clusters, cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0 ), 1, CV_KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS, centers);
```

where

```
image2 = cvLoadImage( "lab.jpg", 0);
points = cvCreateMat( image2->height, image2->width, CV_32FC1 );    
cvConvert(image2, points);
//count= number of clusters.
CvMat* centers; // To store the center of each cluster. (output).
```

lab.jpg is an image in CIE L*a*b* format.

But the above line, while compiling, shows the following errors:

```
`CV_KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS' undeclared (first use in this function) 

too many arguments to function `cvKMeans2'
```

It would be very helpful if someone can point out where am wrong, specially the first error which says KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS undeclared.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [opencv doc](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/clustering_and_search_in_multi-dimensional_spaces.html) for `cvKMeans2`:

> flags – Can be 0 or CV_KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS.

You left out **CV_**.

Edit: also note that there should be **two** arguments between `termcrit` and `flags`, so you are skipping either `attempts` or `rng`. Try

```
cvKMeans2(points, count, &clusters, cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0 ), 1, 0, CV_KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS, centers);
```

Comment: No use. Now it shows "`CV_KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS' undeclared (first use in this function)".

Comment: @Koustav: Just noticed that you're giving the use_initial_labels value to the rng argument instead of flags. Does the suggestion in my edited answer help?

Comment: @Koustav: Which version of OpenCV are you using? In OpenCV 1, cvKmeans2 takes only 4 arguments. The additional 5 optional arguments are only in v2.x. This seems to be the most likely cause of the problem to me now. It would also explain the second error you get.

Comment: yeah, got it!

Am using OpenCV 1.1 actually, so I guess that`s the reason. Thanks a lot mate !! :) :)